# Implement a "Add to collection" in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I'm working on a app where users can find recipes made by chefs. I have implemented already a "like/dislike" fonction but now I would like to give to the user the ability to save a recipe in a collection.
The user can create many collections, so when he want to save a recipe in a collection, he should be able to see his current collections or create a new one.

Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :collections
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :collections
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :recipe_collections
 has_many :recipes, through: :recipe_collections
end

class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :recipe_collections
end

class RecipeCollection < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :recipe
 belongs_to :collection
end
```

my recipe_collections_controller.rb

```
class RecipeCollectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_recipe, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_user, only: [:create]


  def create
    @recipe_collection = @recipe.recipe_collections.build(recipe_collection_params)
    if current_user
      @recipe_collection.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back }
      end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render 'recipes/show' }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = current_user
  end

  def set_recipe
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
  end

  def recipe_collection_params
    params.require(:recipe_collection).permit(:collection_id, :recipe_id, collection_attributes: [:id], recipe_attributes: [:id])
  end

end
```

In the recipe show, I have a render, show.html.erb:

```
<%= render "recipe_collections/form", collection: @recipe_collection || @recipe.recipe_collections.build%>
```

my partial _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for ([ collection.recipe, collection ]) do |form| %>
  <%= form.association :collection, as: :check_boxes %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

my routes.rb

```
  resources :recipes, :concerns => :paginatable do
    member do
      get "like", to: "recipes#upvote"
      get "dislike", to: "recipes#downvote"
    end
    resources :reviews, only: :create
    resources :recipe_collections
  end
```

What is the problem:

1: in my show I have a checkbox form, but it don't display the current user collections but all.

2: when I submit the form, it don't save the recipe in the collection that I chose.

edit:

here are an exemple of my logs when I submit the form.

```
Started POST "/recipes/66/recipe_collections" for ::1 at 2015-04-06 23:58:06 +0200
Processing by RecipeCollectionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"GhMIJs4nNmwsLpzBj4l5ta/OW6fN9dfuzBBnciJsjEa0YlfjQMQYDEmwhcXb9++oEmS36yEbgICNsSdbLgiigA==", "recipe_collection"=>{"collection_id"=>["24", ""]}, "commit"=>"Créer un(e) Recipe collection", "recipe_id"=>"66"}
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "recipes"
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "publishers"
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "votes"
  Recipe Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 66]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
Unpermitted parameter: collection_id
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "recipe_collections" ("recipe_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["recipe_id", 66], ["created_at", "2015-04-06 21:58:06.566948"], ["updated_at", "2015-04-06 21:58:06.566948"]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/recipes/66
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit confusing whether you are setting up a relationship between recipes and collections as many-to-many or one-to-many. Your text implies a collection has many recipes and a recipe belongs to one collection. While your code, by using a join table and stating a recipe has many recipe-collections implies you are setting up a many-to-many relationship.

In other words you are a bit mixed up...

**If a recipe belongs to a collection.** Get rid of the join table. Recipe belongs_to :collection, while Collection has_many :recipes. Get rid of the other relationship stuff in those two models. In your migration table for Recipe, make sure there is a t.belongs_to :collection to set up the foreign key.

**If a recipe has and belongs to many collections.** Keep the join table, but name it collections_recipes as Rails can only find it if both sides are pluralized and in alphabetical order. Recipe has_and_belongs_to_many :collections, Collection has_and_belong_to_many :recipes. Drop the has_many :recipe_collections and the through: bit, do not replace either, Rails does this for you. Check your join table in your migration has t.belongs_to :recipe and :collection

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I change the way to set the collection and now it's working.